# How to disble invisible legend padding in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, highcharts

So I am creating a doughnut chart, using HighCharts. In which I want to customise the legends according to the following reference image:

[image]

And here is the image I could generate:

[image]

SO the first image is reference image and the second I generated with the follwing code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Donut Chart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
   
div.g_Container{
  position: relative;
  
  width: 1000px;
  height: 900px;
  
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="g_Container">
           <div id="g_one"></div>
       
    </div>



<script>
Highcharts.chart('g_one', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        // spacingLeft: 5,
        plotShadow: false,
        width: 536,
        height: 194,
        align: 'left',
        // x:-40,
        // y:75
        
    },
    title: {
            text : '',
    },
    credits: {
            enabled: false
    },
 
    exporting:{
        width: 536,
        height: 194,
        align: 'left',
        // x: -10 
    },
    
    plotOptions: {
       
        pie: {
            slicedOffset: 2,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                
            },
            startAngle: 100,
            endAngle: 100,
            showInLegend : true,
                           
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        // name, percentage of data, color, slicing is need or not//
        keys: ['name', 'y', 'color', 'sliced'],
        size: 168,
        innerSize: 112,
       
        
        // give data name, percentage the data occupies, color to represent the data//
        data: [
        ['Eateris', 10 ,'#22306b', true],
        ['General payments', 10, '#000000', true],
        ['Shoping',10, '#9ca4be', true],
        ['Travel and Transort', 10, '#e1808b', true],
        ['Pastimes', 10, '#6d7272', true],
        ['Family and home', 10, '#6298bf', true],
        ['Utilities', 10, '#4a548e', true],
        ['Health and beauty', 10, '#ab4735', true],
        ['Groceries', 10, '#5e7ab9', true],
        ['Groups and charity', 10, '#d0d1d0', true],            
        ],
            showInLegend: true,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
    }],
    legend: {
        
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        horizontalAlign: 'left',
        height: 800,
        width: 260,
        // itemHeight: 50,
        itemWidth:90,
        
        
        itemStyle: {
                 font: 'Sans Serif Regular',
                
                 fontSize: 8,
                //  paddingBottom: 5 
              },
        labelFormatter: function() {
            return '<span style="color: '+this.color+'">'+ this.name + '</span>';},
        itemHoverStyle: {
                 color: '#444'
              },
        symbolHeight: 10,
       
        

        
    }
});
</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to achieve is, there should be horizontal gaps between the legend items, and the legend texts should come in 2 columns and 5 rows.
I have given the width according to that, so that the legends are getting divided into two columns. But there is a lot of space which remains after the second column of the legend, but yet the legend's text is not coming properly.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you're trying to add some margin to the legends at bottom and you dont want text wrap on the legends.

I suggest you increase your width on the legend.width and set legend.itemWidth to half of it to achieve your 2 column format.

Now coming to margin-bottom

`legend.itemMarginBottom` can be used to achieve it.
The pixel bottom margin for each legend item.

Defaults to 0.

Lastly the text overflow:

```
legend.itemStyle.textOverflow : null
```

Line break style of the element text. Highcharts SVG elements support ellipsis when a width is set.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Donut Chart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
        div.g_Container {
            position: relative;
            width: 1000px;
            height: 900px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="g_Container">
        <div id="g_one"></div>

    </div>



    <script>
        Highcharts.chart('g_one', {
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                // spacingLeft: 5,
                plotShadow: false,
                width: 536,
                height: 194,
                align: 'left',
                // x:-40,
                // y:75

            },
            title: {
                text: '',
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },

            exporting: {
                width: 536,
                height: 194,
                align: 'left',
                // x: -10 
            },

            plotOptions: {

                pie: {
                    slicedOffset: 2,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false,

                    },
                    startAngle: 100,
                    endAngle: 100,
                    showInLegend: true,

                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                // name, percentage of data, color, slicing is need or not//
                keys: ['name', 'y', 'color', 'sliced'],
                size: 168,
                innerSize: 112,


                // give data name, percentage the data occupies, color to represent the data//
                data: [
                    ['Eateris', 10, '#22306b', true],
                    ['General payments', 10, '#000000', true],
                    ['Shoping', 10, '#9ca4be', true],
                    ['Travel and Transort', 10, '#e1808b', true],
                    ['Pastimes', 10, '#6d7272', true],
                    ['Family and home', 10, '#6298bf', true],
                    ['Utilities', 10, '#4a548e', true],
                    ['Health and beauty', 10, '#ab4735', true],
                    ['Groceries', 10, '#5e7ab9', true],
                    ['Groups and charity', 10, '#d0d1d0', true],
                ],
                showInLegend: true,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }],
            legend: {

                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                horizontalAlign: 'left',
                height: 800,
                width: 300,
                itemWidth: 150,
                // itemHeight: 50,
                // itemWidth: 90,


                itemStyle: {
                    font: 'Sans Serif Regular',

                    fontSize: 8,
                    textOverflow: null,
                    //  paddingBottom: 5 
                },
                labelFormatter: function() {
                    console.log(this.name)
                    return '<span style="color: ' + this.color + '">' + this.name + '</span>';
                },
                itemHoverStyle: {
                    color: '#444'
                },
                symbolHeight: 10,
                itemMarginBottom: 5,




            }
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```